# How to remove item of kendo dropDownList if it is the last one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I can remove all items except the last one from the kendo dropdownlist. After the last one is removed, the previous items reappear.

Here is a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/lpoellabauer/Jw4Cz/

```
var dropDown = $("select").data("kendoDropDownList");
var itemToRemove = dropDown.dataSource.at(0);
dropDown.dataSource.remove(itemToRemove);
dropDown.select(0);
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
<option id="none" value="none"></option>
</select>

<a href="#">remove first</a>
```

JS:

```
$("select").kendoDropDownList();

$("a").click(function(){
    var dropDown = $("select").data("kendoDropDownList");
    var itemToRemove = dropDown.dataSource.at(0);
    dropDown.dataSource.remove(itemToRemove);
    dropDown.select(0);
});
$('none').css({display:none});
```

​